# converting plain string into xml

Tags: php, xml, string

I am using an API from the book website biblio, after inputting the parameters and querying a book I get a normal string returned, for some reason they do not return the string in an xml format, My question... is there a simple way to convert plain string to xml in php?

**plain string example**

```
Book ID: 524072799
Author: George R. R. Martin
Title: A Song of Ice and Fire, 7 Volumes 
Description: Harper Voyager, 2012. New and in stock.. Paperback. New. Book. 
ISBN: 9780007477159
Publisher: Harper Voyager
Date: 2012
Currency: GBP
Price: 55.00
Bookseller: El Pinarillo Books 
Bookseller_Location: GBR
URL: http://www.biblio.com/details.php?dcx=524072799
Shipping Ground: 3.15 
Shipping Expedited: 3.95
```

Comment: Why do you need it to be in xml format? if you are going to reconvert it to text again there is no point

Comment: Do you have the option of specifying an Accept type when executing the call to the API? It may return in plain text as default.

Comment: @Ibu because it would be better to work with xml than preg_match

Comment: @tomasmcguinness there documentation fits on 1 page, it says nothing about returning results in xml format, I've also emailed them with no response.

Comment: Try putting Accept: text/xml into the headers when making the request to the API and see if it has any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative, you can take advantage of php array (no preg_match needed or XML):

```
// The string returned;
$string = <<<STRING
Book ID: 524072799
Author: George R. R. Martin
......
Shipping Ground: 3.15 
Shipping Expedited: 3.95
STRING;
```

You can start by spliting it per line

```
$lines = explode("\n",$string);
```

Then you save it as key pair value in an array

```
$result = array();
foreach($lines as $line){
   list($key,value) = explode(":",$line);
   $result[trim($key)] = trim($value);
}
```

Now you can access anyline like so

```
echo $result['Book ID']; // 524072799
echo $result['Author']; //  George R. R. Martin
```

and so on. I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: the first explode is fine, it puts every line into an array, but there must be an error in the for loop as $result returns empty

Comment: you can do a print_f($line) in the loop to see what is the problem

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I've found a small bug with the url explode, because the url contains a colon e.g. http:// this code will also explode the url, how do I make sure I only explode the first colon?

Comment: im not sure if this is gonna be consistent, but a solution will be to add a space after your colon, `explode(": ",$line);`, this way the http:// will not match and will be ignored

Comment: it's ok i've found another solution, `explode(":", $line, 2)` limits the explode

Answer (score 1):

Just use an `explode("\n",$text)` and `foreach()` loop to write the file:

```
$xml="<book>";
$rows = explode("\n",$text);
foreach($rows as $row){
   $pieces = explode(':',$row); //get the tag and value
   $tag = str_replace(' ','_',strtolower($pieces[0])); //make sure the tag is valid
   if (!isset($pieces[1])){$pieces[1]="";} //make sure there is a value
   $xml.="<$tag>".$pieces[1]."</$tag>\n";//add it to the xml
}
$xml.="</book>";
```

Answer (score 1):

If your sure there is no option to get back xml or json you could do it like this.

**Create an array from the response:**

```
<?php 
$str = 'Book ID: 524072799
Author: George R. R. Martin
Title: A Song of Ice and Fire, 7 Volumes 
Description: Harper Voyager, 2012. New and in stock.. Paperback. New. Book. 
ISBN: 9780007477159
Publisher: Harper Voyager
Date: 2012
Currency: GBP
Price: 55.00
Bookseller: El Pinarillo Books 
Bookseller_Location: GBR
URL: http://www.biblio.com/details.php?dcx=524072799
Shipping Ground: 3.15 
Shipping Expedited: 3.95
';

$lines = explode('<br />',nl2br($str));

$array = array();
foreach($lines as $line){
    $line = trim($line);
    if(empty($line)){continue;}
    $line_parts = explode(':',$line);
    $array[$line_parts[0]] = $line_parts[1];
}
/*
You now have Array
(
    [Book ID] =>  524072799
    [Author] =>  George R. R. Martin
    [Title] =>  A Song of Ice and Fire, 7 Volumes
    [Description] =>  Harper Voyager, 2012. New and in stock.. Paperback. New. Book.
    [ISBN] =>  9780007477159
    [Publisher] =>  Harper Voyager
    [Date] =>  2012
    [Currency] =>  GBP
    [Price] =>  55.00
    [Bookseller] =>  El Pinarillo Books
    [Bookseller_Location] =>  GBR
    [URL] =>  http
    [Shipping Ground] =>  3.15
    [Shipping Expedited] =>  3.95
)
*/
?>
```

**Then create XML from that array:**

```
<?php
//To create and output xml from the given array
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><books/>');

$node = $xml->addChild('book');
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $node->addChild(str_replace(' ','_',$key), trim($value));
}

//DOMDocument to format code output
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());

echo $dom->saveXML();
/*
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
  <book>
    <Book_ID>524072799</Book_ID>
    <Author>George R. R. Martin</Author>
    <Title>A Song of Ice and Fire, 7 Volumes</Title>
    <Description>Harper Voyager, 2012. New and in stock.. Paperback. New. Book.</Description>
    <ISBN>9780007477159</ISBN>
    <Publisher>Harper Voyager</Publisher>
    <Date>2012</Date>
    <Currency>GBP</Currency>
    <Price>55.00</Price>
    <Bookseller>El Pinarillo Books</Bookseller>
    <Bookseller_Location>GBR</Bookseller_Location>
    <URL>http</URL>
    <Shipping_Ground>3.15</Shipping_Ground>
    <Shipping_Expedited>3.95</Shipping_Expedited>
  </book>
</books>
*/
?>
```